# Transfer US-H1b dossier from one consulate to another

Tags: h1-visa

There are several pages available online on the nitty-gritty of transferring H1B from one employer to another. However, can an H1B file be transferred from one consulate to another?

**Here is the situation:**

I am an Indian citizen. I have been offered a job in the USA starting May 2015 at a university (exempt from H1B cap or some such). I am currently working in Paris France and hence the university who want to employ me from May 2015 would like to petition for my H1B in Oct and send my "file" to the Paris US consulate in Oct 2014. If I were to quit my job in Paris AFTER H1B petition is made for the Paris consulate, can this be transferred to a US consulate in India?

I am looking for if this is possible.
A solution is for the US university to "hold it" until I quit my job but for several reasons, that option may not be available to me since my situation is fickle.

Please do let me know if any further information would be useful for this question.